# i am trying to get the same result which i have already received using raw query in eloquent. Here is my table looks like

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

id  sent_by message         read    received_by created_at  updated_at

```
1       7   Hello Mam hello 1           1       2018-04-03 16:53:56 2018-04-03 18:20:47 
2       1   Hello Mam hello 1           6       2018-04-03 16:54:12 2018-04-03 18:20:35 
3       7   Hello Mam hello 1           1       2018-04-03 16:54:21 2018-04-03 18:20:47 
4       1   Hello Mam hello 1           7       2018-04-03 16:55:34 2018-04-03 18:20:47 
7       6   Hello Mam hello 1           1       2018-04-03 17:34:02 2018-04-03 18:20:35 
8       6   Hello Mam hello 0           1       2018-04-03 19:21:03 2018-04-03 19:21:03
```

I have this eloquent query which not works for

```
$list=ChatMessage::whereIn('id', function($query)  {
$query->selectRaw('MAX(id) id')
    ->from('chat_message')
    ->where('received_by', 1)
    ->orWhere('sent_by', 1`enter code here`)
    ->groupBy('sent_by');
})->with('sender_dtl','received_by_dtl')->orderBy('created_at','Desc')
->get();
```

From which here is my output looks like:

```
    id sent_by message             read    received_by  created_at    updated_at
    8       6   Hello Mam hello     0           1       2018-04-03 19:21:03 2018-04-03 19:21:03 
    4       1   Hello Mam hello     1           7       2018-04-03 16:55:34 2018-04-03 18:20:47
```

Comment: because of your are using group by that's why returns combine values

Comment: What's your question? How should the result look?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $list=ChatMessage::whereIn('id', function($query)  {
$query->selectRaw('MAX(id) id')
    ->from('chat_message')
    ->where('received_by', 1)
    ->orWhere('sent_by', 1`enter code here`)
    })->with('sender_dtl','received_by_dtl')->orderBy('created_at','Desc')
->get();
```